# Odd Behavior in React Application when updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a difficult time sorting out what my problem is here, I have a react component which calls a function passed in from it's parent as a prop.  The function is being executed as expected. However, in that function I'd like to call a second function on the parent twice, each time updating the state. For some reason the state is not updated between calls. This is for a pretty simple tic-tac-toe application and I'm attempting to take in the users move (as a click on a child component), place the players move and then place the AI's move. Then allow the player to click another open square.

Here's the relevant code:

```
updateBoard(loc) {
    if(this.state.gameBoard[loc] === 'x' || this.state.gameBoard[loc]=== 'o'    || this.state.winner !== null){
      //invalid move
      return;
    }
    let currentGameBoard = this.state.gameBoard;
    currentGameBoard.splice(loc, 1, this.state.turn);
      //Check if there is a winner or draw
      if (this.winner(currentGameBoard, this.state.turn)){
       this.setState({gameBoard: currentGameBoard, winner: this.state.turn});
       return;
     } else if(this.tie(currentGameBoard)) {
       //Make game over component visible
       this.setState({gameBoard: currentGameBoard, winner: 'd'});
       return;
     }
     this.setState({gameBoard: currentGameBoard, turn: this.state.turn === 'x' ? 'o' : 'x'});
   }

   gameLoop(move){
     this.updateBoard(move);
     this.updateBoard(this.findAiMove(this.state.gameBoard));
   }
```

For some reason the first move occurs correctly. The first X is placed wherever the player clicks, but the AI move does not happen at all. An additional click on the board will place 2 o's and then 2 x's and 2 o's until the game ends. A click by the player calls `gameLoop()` and then calls `updateBoard()` with the players move and with the AI move. The move is a simple integer which is the array index of the move to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is asynchronous, so there's no guarantee that the state will have updated between successive calls.

This means that if you call your `updateBoard` method twice, the state might not have updated from the first call in time for the second call to read the new value.

One way to fix your problem would be to use the callback argument of `setState`, which is fired once the state has updated:

```
updateBoard(loc, callback) {
    if(this.state.gameBoard[loc] === 'x' || this.state.gameBoard[loc]=== 'o'    || this.state.winner !== null){
      //invalid move
      return;
    }
    let currentGameBoard = this.state.gameBoard;
    currentGameBoard.splice(loc, 1, this.state.turn);
    let stateUpdate;
      //Check if there is a winner or draw
      if (this.winner(currentGameBoard, this.state.turn)){
       stateUpdate = { gameBoard: currentGameBoard, winner: this.state.turn };
     } else if(this.tie(currentGameBoard)) {
       //Make game over component visible
       stateUpdate = { gameBoard: currentGameBoard, winner: 'd'};
     } else {
       stateUpdate = { gameBoard: currentGameBoard, turn: this.state.turn === 'x' ? 'o' : 'x'};
     }

     this.setState(stateUpdate, callback);
   }

   gameLoop(move){
     this.updateBoard(move, () => this.updateBoard(this.findAiMove(this.state.gameBoard)));
   }
```

Now the second state update is always executed after the first.